# How to prevent deploying contract from quorum node

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, quorum

In quorum network, every node can deploy smart contract. How can I prevent the node from deploying smart contract or allow only specific node to do this.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "privateFor" field while deploying contract.In privateFor object pass the publicKey of participant node. Please refer below code:

```
web3.eth.contract(contract.abi).new({
            data: "0x" + contract.bytecode,
            gas: 80000000,
            privateFor: ["bvpFyZCYmtPX3hyxNhmPXu0Rn/95S3IoqyK+IiZPlHw="],
            from: owner,
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, But that is not what I meant. 
I want to prevent someone from deploying smart contract in my private network, say, the bad guy deploys one billions contracts to my network, It's not good, right?

Comment: Have you set a password while installing node? if not then set the password while installing quorum node.So who have password those users able unlock the account  and deploy the contracts.

Comment: People can download the quorum node, connect to my network and deploy smart contract on their node. This smart contract will be added to blockchain, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using enhanced permissioning for Quorum.
https://consensys.net/docs/goquorum/en/latest/configure-and-manage/manage/enhanced-permissions/